# How to fill a fillable PDF Form with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems

i would like to fill a pdf with data from a form/database (like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJNCc2GwREA&t=190s but i didn't see any gem for that is this even possible ?

i dont want to create html page and generate a pdf like [prawn](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails) or [wicked PDF](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails).

Do u have any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this gem would do the trick - https://github.com/tcocca/active_pdftk

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).